# How to hide Author name and Site page name from the modern site page in SPOnline team site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, sitepages

I am working with modern team site created in SPOnline. From the site pages library, I have created a site page and as you know, on this site page, author name and page name becomes visible by default and I believe there is no OOTB way to hide it.

However I am using modern script editor web part so can someone please help me with right css classes to set display:none for those classes.

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the method mentioned by UBK, which meets your needs.

Before:

[image]

Remove profile and Page title：
[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

not sure if I have understood your problem correctly, but for the 'Author Name', you can chose to remove it, in which case it would be blank and will not be shown in the published version. As per the site title, I am not sure the reason why you have to hide it, but you can chose to remove the title once the page is saved and it both title and author place holders will not be shown in the published view.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have added the screenshot in question description, I did not mention hiding site title. I am looking to hide Page title and author name for a modern site page.